# jQuery Cross slide

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a Cross slide effect in this slide show, but I can't get it work. The problem is, that I want the transition for a div background-image. Hope someone can help me out. (HTML and CSS work fine as the fade in/fade out via animate work)

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var imgArr = new Array( // relative paths of images
'images/slide3.jpg',
'images/slide4.jpg',
'images/slide3.jpg',
'images/slide4.jpg'
 );

var preloadArr = new Array();
var i;

/* preload images */
for(i=0; i < imgArr.length; i++){
preloadArr[i] = new Image();
preloadArr[i].src = imgArr[i];
}

var currImg = 1;
var intID = setInterval(changeImg, 6000);

/* image rotator */
function changeImg(){
$('#parallax-background').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function(){
$(this).css('background','url(' + preloadArr[currImg++%preloadArr.length].src +') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed');
}).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: did you include the jquery file?